# How to skip undefined/missing values in key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, key-value

I'm trying to build a citation generator from json in an API with data about images, stored in key-value pairs. I can get the data to return to the screen, but it always includes undefined in the citation. [Sample manifest](https://teva.contentdm.oclc.org/iiif/info/p15138coll25/1421/manifest.json) returns undefined as the creator since that isn't listed in this particular record. How can I keep any undefined value from being returned? I've tried changing the forEach to map, filtering at allMetadata by string length, using if !== undefined at insertCitation, and versions of those in different spots in the code.

EDIT: updated to provide full code, including print to page

```
(function () {
'use strict';

const buildCitation = {
    buildMetadataObject: async function (collAlias, itemID) {
        let response = await fetch('/iiif/info/' + collAlias + '/' + itemID + '/manifest.json');
        let data = await response.json()
        let allMetadata = data.metadata
        let citationData = {};
        allMetadata.forEach(function (kvpair) {
            if (kvpair.value == undefined) {
                return false;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Title') {
                citationData.itemTitle = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Creator') {
                citationData.itemCreator = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Repository') {
                citationData.itemRepository = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Collection Name') {
                citationData.itemCollection = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Owning Institution') {
                citationData.itemOwning = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Date') {
                citationData.itemDate = kvpair.value;
            } else if (kvpair.label === 'Storage Location') {
                citationData.itemStorage = kvpair.value;
            }
        return true;
        });
        return citationData;
    },
    insertCitation: function (data) {
        var testTitle = data.itemTitle;
        console.log(testTitle);
        const itemCite = `Citation: "${data.itemTitle}," ${data.itemDate}, ${data.itemCreator}, ${data.itemCollection}, ${data.itemOwning}, ${data.itemStorage}, ${data.itemRepository}.`;
        const citationContainer = document.createElement('div');
        citationContainer.id = 'citation';
        citationContainer.innerHTML = itemCite;

        // CHANGED to innerHTML instead of innerText because you may want to format it at some point as HTML code.

        if (testTitle) {
            document.querySelector('.ItemView-itemViewContainer').appendChild(citationContainer);
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('cdm-item-page:ready', async function (e) {
    const citationData = await buildCitation.buildMetadataObject(e.detail.collectionId, e.detail.itemId);
    console.log({ citationData });
    buildCitation.insertCitation(citationData);
});

document.addEventListener('cdm-item-page:update', async function (e) {
    document.getElementById('citation').remove();
    const citationData = await buildCitation.buildMetadataObject(e.detail.collectionId, e.detail.itemId);
    console.log({ citationData });
    buildCitation.insertCitation(citationData);
});
```

})();

Comment: Hi there. could you elaborate as to what `undefined` means for you ?

Comment: Not sure what is `undefined` here, I ran your code and it seems to return an object which doesn't have any undefined properties or values, `{
  "itemTitle": "Market Street",
  "itemCreator": "Calvert Brothers",
  "itemCollection": "Library Photograph Collection",
  "itemOwning": "Tennessee State Library and Archives",
  "itemStorage": "Drawer 18, Folder 184",
  "itemRepository": "Tennessee Virtual Archive"
}`

Comment: What is the purpose of returning a boolean from the callback of `forEach`? The said method doesn't do anything with the returned value, returning from the callback just moves the iteration to the next round.

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsbin.com/hoyavax/edit?js,console) - I do not see any error. I do not even see how you can have an error, since JSON doesn't even have any way to mark `undefined` - that value cannot exist after deserialisation.

Comment: @NisanthReddy undefined means it doesn't exist. There is no value for that pair. It doesn't show up in the record, but when I apply the code [something shows up as undefined](https://teva.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p15138coll25/id/1421/rec/21).

Comment: @VLAZ I edited to include the full code- that must mean that the error is in the last two event listeners?

Comment: @TeVA  I've edited my answer to skip the undefined values. I put `itemTitle` in a blacklist because it's displayed manually between quotes, whereas the other fields are displayed normally.

Comment: @bel3atar that's working, the result in the console looks good. Thanks! Now I need to get the event listener working correctly to print that to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your program. The undefined is coming from the fact that there is no item with label `Date`

```js
const mappings = {
  Date: 'itemDate',
  Title: 'itemTitle',
  Creator: 'itemCreator',
  Repository: 'itemRepository',
  'Storage Location': 'itemStorage',
  'Owning Institution': 'itemOwning',
  'Collection Name': 'itemCollection',
}
async function buildMetadataObject(collAlias, itemID) {
  let response = await fetch('https://teva.contentdm.oclc.org/iiif/info/p15138coll25/1421/manifest.json');
  let data = await response.json()
  return data.metadata.reduce(
    (acc, { label, value }) => ({ ...acc, [ mappings[label] ]: value }),
    {}
  )
}

function insertCitation(data) {
  var testTitle = data.itemTitle;
  const fieldBlackList = ['itemTitle'];
  const itemCite = `Citation: "${data.itemTitle}," ${
    Object.values(mappings).reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (fieldBlackList.includes(cur)) return acc;
      const value = data[cur]; 
      return value ? [...acc, value] : acc 
    }, []).join(', ')
  }.`;
  console.log(itemCite);
}
//MAIN PROGRAM
(async() => {
  const citationData = await buildMetadataObject();
  insertCitation(citationData);
})()
```